# (easy) rearranging of power series denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teacher has done this:
$$\frac{1}{z^3(1-z^2/3+O(z^4))} = \frac{1+z^2/3+O(z^4)}{z^3}$$
How does that work? I don't understand why he can claim this.

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: It's 4. I edited the expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't it simply because $\frac{1}{1-u} = 1+u+O(u^2)$ ?

Comment: In case OP finds this a little opaque, the idea is to let $u=z^2/3-O(x^4)$ and notice that $u^2=O(z^4)$.

Comment: @Gerry, thanks for fleshing it out.

Comment: Thanks all! I feel so stupid.

Comment: @A. Top: Don't! This happens to all of us :) Next time you'll remember.